# C++ WriteConsoleOutput Display Issues

Tags: c++, winapi

I've started making a simple game in c++.

At this stage I have all the characters and attributes (tiles) stored in a file that is then loaded in to CHAR_INFO. Then using the WriteConsoleOutputA I can basically paint the map/world.

That all appears to work correctly and there is no display issues. However when I start to move my character around he is mucking up the tiles. It a bit hard to explain so here is a little video. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5Be5qz30r8.

As you can see there is not problem with the green tiles (foreground and background are same colour). But when I go near the grey tiles it isn't working as intended.

main.cpp snippet...

```
int main()
{
    while (0 < 1)
    {

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) || GetAsyncKeyState(0x57))
            player.Move('u');
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) || GetAsyncKeyState(0x53))
            player.Move('d');
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(0x41))
            player.Move('l');
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) || GetAsyncKeyState(0x44))
            player.Move('r');

        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Character class snippet

```
void Character::Move(char d)
{
    COORD oldLoc = loc;
    char walkableTiles[12] = {
        4, 179, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 217, 218, 255
    };

    //set character
        switch (d) 
    {
        case 'u' :
            loc.Y--;
            break;
        case 'd':
            loc.Y++;
            break;
        case 'l':
            loc.X--;
            break;
        case 'r':
            loc.X++;
            break;
    }

    //setup the buffer and location of tiles
    CHAR_INFO newTile[1];
    COORD buffSize = {1,1};
    COORD buffPos = {0,0};
    SMALL_RECT newBuffArea = {loc.X, loc.Y, loc.X, loc.Y};
    SMALL_RECT oldBuffArea = {oldLoc.X, oldLoc.Y, oldLoc.X, oldLoc.Y};

    //store newTile info
    ReadConsoleOutputA(outHnd, newTile, buffSize, buffPos, &newBuffArea);
    //check if newTile is valid
    bool valid = 0; // assume not valid
    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(walkableTiles); i++)
    {
        if (newTile[0].Char.AsciiChar == walkableTiles[i])
            valid = 1;
    }

    if (!valid)
    {
        loc = oldLoc;
        return;
    }

    //restore oldTile information
    WriteConsoleOutputA(outHnd, oldTile, buffSize, buffPos, &oldBuffArea);

    //newTile becomes oldTile
    oldTile[0] = newTile[0];

    //get bg of newTile and set character/attributes
    int bg = (newTile[0].Attributes & Blue << BG ) | (newTile[0].Attributes & Red << BG) | (newTile[0].Attributes & Green << BG) | (newTile[0].Attributes & BACKGROUND_INTENSITY);
    newTile[0].Char.AsciiChar = 1;
    newTile[0].Attributes = White | bg;

    //place character on newTile
    WriteConsoleOutputA(outHnd, newTile, buffSize, buffPos, &newBuffArea);
```

Apologies for the code, this is my first game.

Comment: What is the desired behavior? I don't see any tiles getting mucked up.

Comment: If you have a look as the character runs left over some tiles it appears to move them left 2 pixels creating a gap in them. But as you run right over them they are fine.

Comment: Looking into this a bit further it appears as if the characters are overlapping. When we're writing characters from right to left this will cause an issue.